# How to pass c# datagridview selected cell values to SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have a datagridview on C# form which has large number of rows. And selection option with check boxes.

If I select 10 rows using check box selection I need to pass a column select row value to a SQL query to filter the records from another table.

Below is my coding but its not working i don't how to solve this problem.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=acc;Integrated Security=True");
     SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"select db.date,db.type,db.refno,db.itmcod,db.qty,db.cuscod, db.cstcod,cus.cusnam INTO ##wec from fstktxn as db INNER JOIN fcustomer as cus on db.cuscod = cus.cuscod where itmcod = "dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["title"].Value", ", conn1);

     conn1.Open();
     cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

     SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn1);
     bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "##tmp1";

     conn1.Close();
}
```

Is there any solution to filter the data using gridview selection?

Comment: What are you trying to *do* here? You have a query (`cmd`) that you are executing with `ExecuteNonQuery`, so that does nothing whatsoever. You have a `SqlBulkCopy` that you never call `WriteToServer()` on, and indeed you don't mention anything in the question about bulk copy. What are you trying to do? You mention some UI elements, but they aren't touched at all in your code. The question is very very unclear.

Comment: need to filter datas from a sql table using a datagridview selection

Comment: filter how? what is `j` in the code? what is the intended result? what is meant to happen? are you asking "how can I make this an `in` query?" ? Are you trying to filter the data on screen? or the data fetched?

Comment: Oh, also: never never never concatenate input into a query; that is a huge SQL injection problem. Please, please please never do that.

Comment: how to insert those selected row values to sql query

Comment: You're adding words, but that isn't explaining anything. Let me give an example, and you tell me whether this is right, or if not: say something similar: "I have a `DataGridView` with multiple rows; one of the columns is a checkbox; depending on which check-boxes are checked, I want to run a second query so that only rows with `itmcod` in the set of checked values is returned (where the per-row value to use comes from another column in the `DataGridView`); how can I do that?" - is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you are requirements you should be doing something like this.

First get you datagridveiw data.

```
DataTable data=datfridviewname.DataSource as DataTable;
                con.Open();
                SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
                sbc.DestinationTableName = @"tableName";
                sbc.WriteToServer(data);
```

Comment: I don't think they are actually trying to do a `SqlBulkCopy`

Comment: this is ok but the problem is using gridview selected rows to a sql query where clause to filter datas to a temp table. i need to know how to do that

Comment: @RaziAngel your question doesn't ask that, and this answer doesn't answer that; so...

Answer (score 0):

Try reading up on this [How to use parameterised queries in SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

It shows how to add variables into your queries safely

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're asking is "how can I use the selected rows in a `DataGridView` to form an `in` query?". Assuming that is try, you should break this into two steps:

1. obtain (from the UI) the set of values that should be used in the `in` query
2. compose and create the `in` query

The first step can be done by iterating over the `.Rows` of the `DataGridView`, and checking the `.Checked` value of (presumably) the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` that you have; if it is checked: add the *filter value* to some list. For example:

```
List<string> titles = new List<string>();
foreach (GridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)  
{  
    if(row.Cells["CheckBoxColumnName"].Value == true)
    {
        titles.Add((string)row.Cells["TitleColumnName"].Value);
    }
}
```

The second step is more complex, unless you are using a tool like "dapper" that automates it. If you *are* using "dapper", you could just use:

```
var rows  = connection.Query<YourDataType>("...some query... where someColumn in @titles",
   new {titles}).AsList();
```

and *that would be it*. If not, you'll need to write the command manually, for example:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder("...the basic query... where someColumn in (");
int index = 0;
var cmd = new SqlCommand(connection); // see also: "using"
foreach(var title in titles) {
    if(index != 0) sb.Append(",");
    string name = "@title" + index++;
    sb.Append(name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, value);
}
sb.Append(")");
cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();
```

then execute the command as usual. You may need to think about the zero case, too; should that be all rows? no rows?

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to get the selected checkbox rows then by using this you can get it

```
 protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in dataGridView1.Rows)  
        {  
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkSelect");  
            if (chk != null & chk.Checked)  
            {  
                SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=acc;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"select db.date,db.type,db.refno,db.itmcod,db.qty,db.cuscod, db.cstcod,cus.cusnam INTO ##wec from fstktxn as db INNER JOIN fcustomer as cus on db.cuscod = cus.cuscod where itmcod = "dataGridView1.Cells["title"].Value", ", conn1);
                conn1.Open();
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
               SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn1);
               bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "##tmp1";
               conn1.Close();//Do something 
            }  
        }         
    }
```